# Testing Mailgun batch sending with gmail '+' aliases

Tags: mailgun

I'm currently trying to integrate Mailgun to send mails in batch. To test the batch sending, I decided to use a list of 10 email aliases to my own address, using a "+" alias.

For example, I'd use a list like this:

- myaddress+1@gmail.com
- myaddress+2@gmail.com
- myaddress+3@gmail.com
- etc.

To call mailgun, I'm only using a POST http call, reproducing the curl example from the Mailgun documentation.

The problem is that when I use aliases, I only receive the email once, on a random alias (e.g. myaddress+3@gmail.com). In Mailgun's logs, all the 10 emails appear as delivered.

Is this problem coming from Gmail which would filter similar mails arriving at once ? Has anyone encountered this type of problem before ?

When I add a different address (not an alias), the latter seems to receive the email correctly, but I'd like to understand why the email couldn't be sent several times to the same address.

Comment: did you managed to solve this?
I currently have a problem when mails send to gmail aliases with plus sign are not send.